# How to apply function in each row in data.table

Tags: r, data.table

Supposed I have the following

```
dt <- data.table(a=c(T,T,F,F), b= c(T,F,T,F))
```

return,

```
       a     b
1:  TRUE  TRUE
2:  TRUE FALSE
3: FALSE  TRUE
4: FALSE FALSE
```

I have tried to use `function(x) min(which(x))` to determine the first `TRUE` of each row in `dt`, but it did not work.  The result that I expect will be

```
       a     b index
1:  TRUE  TRUE     1
2:  TRUE FALSE     1
3: FALSE  TRUE     2
4: FALSE FALSE  9999
```

,where the index column represents the position of first `TRUE` and 9999 is used when that row contains only FALSE

**FYI:** In the real data, I have around 50 columns that contains TRUE and FALSE

Could you please give me suggestions?

Comment: Try `dt[, index := ifelse(a, 1, ifelse(b, 2, 9999))]`  I am not sure about the 50 column case.  Are you saying that you have TRUE, FALSE, 50 columns.  In that case, `max.col(dt, 'first')*(!rowSums(dt))` would be the way

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen  Just commenting on my free time.

Comment: Try `max.col(dt,ties.method="first")*(rowSums(dt)!=0)` if you don't mind `0` instead of `9999` as indicator of all `FALSE` (you can also set it to 9999 afterwise).

Comment: @nicola was just going to propose the same. Though `rowSums` could be an ovehead here.

Comment: @DavidArenburg Also `max.col` is. They both coerce to `matrix`. My proposed solution is faster if his object is a matrix.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For 50 columns, it is better to use `max.col`

```
dt$index <- max.col(dt, 'first') *(!!rowSums(dt))
```

Or as @David Arenburg mentioned, more idiomatic code would be

```
dt[, indx := max.col(.SD,ties.method="first")*(!!rowSums(.SD))]
```

If we need `9999`

```
 (max.col(dt)*(!!rowSums(dt))) + (!rowSums(dt))*9999
```

Comment: @nicola Before you proposed, I did updated the comments, please check

Comment: Ok, I see. Guess this exact question has been asked several times (and this exact solution also).

Comment: `dt[, indx := max.col(.SD,ties.method="first")*(!!rowSums(.SD))]` is probably more idiomatic

Comment: Though this whole thing would probably better suit for a matrix in the first place because both `max.col` and `rowSums` convert to a matrix.

Answer (score 2):

A bit late but this is a way:

```
#initial data.table - added a row id
dt <- data.table(a=c(T,T,F,F), b= c(T,F,T,F))[, id := .I]

#if the row sums equal 0 then 9999 else pick the first max i.e. the first TRUE
dt[, index := if(rowSums(.SD)==0) 9999 else as.double(which.max(.SD)), by=id]
```

Or as per @David's comment, in order to avoid the matrix conversion:

```
dt[, index := if(Reduce('+', .SD)==0) 9999 else as.double(which.max(.SD)), by=id]
```

Output:

```
> dt
       a     b id index
1:  TRUE  TRUE  1     1
2:  TRUE FALSE  2     1
3: FALSE  TRUE  3     2
4: FALSE FALSE  4  9999
```

Comment: @DavidArenburg Yeah you are right Dave. Much better. I ll add it. Thanks.

Comment: I would worry more about looping over the rows than about matrix conversion.

Comment: @Roland Yeah I agree on this. I posted just as a supplement since the title is a bit more generic. It might help someone with a different problem.

Answer (score 2):

Also,

```
ans = rep_len(9999L, nrow(dt))
for(i in length(dt):1L) ans[dt[[i]]] = i
ans
#[1]    1    1    2 9999
```